# Siglas e abreviações pontuadas sucedidas por ponto final

Tags: pontuação, siglas

Em siglas que sejam pontuadas, como I.N.S.S., que estejam no final de uma frase, há necessidade do ponto final?

> Ele recorreu ao I.N.S.S..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não, o ponto da sigla ou abreviação serve também de ponto final. Eis o que diz a *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 816):

> Além de servir para marcar uma pausa longa, o ponto tem outra utilidade. É o sinal que se emprega depois de qualquer palavra escrita abreviadamente. Assim: *V. S.ª (Vossa Senhoria), Dr. (Doutor), C. F. C. (Conselho Federal de Cultura), I. N. I. C. (Instituto Nacional de Investigação Científica).* Note-se que, se a palavra assim reduzida estiver no fim de período, este encerra-se com o ponto abreviativo, pois não se coloca outro ponto depois dele.

Comment: Muito obrigado por terem me tirado essa dúvida.