# Siglas e abreviações pontuadas sucedidas por reticências

Tags: gramática, pontuação, siglas

Em siglas que sejam pontuadas, como I.N.S.S., que estejam no final de uma frase, como se deve usar a reticências?

> Ele recorreu ao I.N.S.S...

ou

> Ele recorreu ao I.N.S.S....

Comment: Acho que não se vê muito esse tipo de exemplo. Mas quatro pontos me parece exagerado.

Comment: Relacionada: [Siglas e abreviações pontuadas sucedidas por ponto final](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4805/2764).

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a gramática de Cunha e Cintra (via [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ponto-no-final-da-frase-apos-ponto-da-abreviatura/31884)):

> se a palavra assim reduzida [i.e., abreviada, com ponto] estiver no fim do período, este encerra-se com o ponto abreviativo, pois não se coloca outro ponto depois dele

Por analogia, se pode argumentar que três pontos bastam ("Recorreu ao I.N.S.S...").

Contudo, a filóloga Eunice Marta afirma, na mesma resposta do Ciberdúvidas:

> No entanto, a situação é diferente, se a frase terminar com qualquer outro sinal de pontuação.

Ou seja, na frase "O problema do I.N.S.S.: Falta de recursos", não seria aceitável considerar que os dois pontos podem ser construídos com um ponto sobre o último da abreviação ("I.N.S.S:").

E, como reticências não são necessariamente uma sequência de três pontos finais, mas um sinal em si, o mesmo argumento se aplicaria a elas, e o correto seria "I.N.S.S.…".

Pessoalmente, me parece ser uma questão de estilo.

Comment: Ainda interessa notar que a reticências pode ser considerada um só símbolo, como “…”, em vez de “...”.

Comment: @Schilive Sim, inclusive é o que usei em "I.N.S.S.…" (`I.N.S.S.…`), mas a página exibe sem diferenciar.

Comment: Agora diferencia... magia... ficou foi maior que o deus me livre... possivelmente pior a emenda que o soneto...

Comment: @Jacinto De fato ficou pior. :-) E eu me referia ao navegador diferenciar entre três pontos, `...` e o caractere de reticências, `…`, porque no editor a diferença é marcante ([veja](https://imgur.com/a/WpfYqRk)), enquanto ela é muita discreta na visualização da página ([veja](https://imgur.com/TuUeHPW)). Penso que introduzir o espaço é ruim também por permitir a interpretação que uma palavra está sendo omitida, por isso reverti a edição.